# Does ojdbc still use CharacterConverter002e.glb?

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, ojdbc

In my web-based application, we've recently implemented language (utf-8) support. Since we have gotten it working, I have had the following error message spammed in my tomcat output. I don't have to have the web page open, only the application deployed, and this starts printing to the output at exact 30 second intervals, 5 times per interval.

```
Oct 09, 2013 4:26:46 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  
Could not load oracle/sql/converter_xcharset/CharacterConverter002e.glb.  The 
eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes 
as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and 
has no functional impact.
```

I am using ojdbc6 and see that there isn't anything like "CharacterConverter002e.glb" in the library. What is causing my application to look for this? Am I using the wrong ojdbc? It doesn't appear to keep anything from working but it's bothersome.